# How to refer SASS variable

Tags: css, sass

I have this in my SASS:

```
$colors: (
  primary:    #f6861f,
  secondary:  #32db64,
  danger:     #f53d3d,
  light:      #f4f4f4,
  dark:       #222
);
```

If I use

```
.menu-inner .scroll-content{
    background: $colors['primary'];
}
```

it doesn't work. How do I refer to `primary` inside my `$colors` array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax isn't quite right - you can't use C-style associative arrays with SASS; you need to use the `map-get` function instead.

In your example, to access the primary colour you would do this:

```
.menu-inner .scroll-content {
    background: map-get($colors, primary);
}
```

There's some more info on SASS maps in [these](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-sass-maps/) [articles](http://erskinedesign.com/blog/friendlier-colour-names-sass-maps/).